# Why aren't my callback methods working properly?

Tags: java, asynchronous, callback, resttemplate, spring-web

I use AsyncRestTemplate to make resttemplate asynchronously.

These methods should wait all asyncresttemplate processes till done, And It will return reviewContent.

Problem is callback methods are not working, before the entire method works done. So I can't take proper return value of optionName and membershipGradeCode and reviewType should be included in reviewContent.

Could someone explain what am I missing now?

rev#1
Success callback methods change the state of reviewContent, Could it be a problem?

```
public ReviewContent getRepresentativeReviewContent(Long dealNo, Long categoryNo, String setId) {

    Optional<Map<String, Object>> review = Optional.ofNullable(boardApi.getRepresentativeReviewContent(dealNo));

    if (review.isPresent()) {
        Long memberNo = Long.valueOf(review.get().get("memberNo").toString());
        ReviewContent reviewContent  = new ReviewContent();

        ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<Map>> optionInfo = dealApi.asyncGetDealOption(Long.valueOf(review.get().get("optionNo").toString()));
        optionInfo.addCallback(success -> {
            try {
                reviewContent.setOptionName((String) ((Map<String, Object>) success.getBody().get("data")).get("dealTitle"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                reviewContent.setOptionName(null);
            }
        }, failure -> LOGGER.error("asyncGetDealOption", failure.getStackTrace()));

        ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<Map>> gradeInfoOfThisMember = mktApi.asyncGetMembershipGradeOfThisMember(memberNo);
        gradeInfoOfThisMember.addCallback(success -> {
                    try {
                        reviewContent.setMembershipGradeCode((Integer) ((Map<String, Object>) success.getBody().get("data")).get("grade"));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        reviewContent.setMembershipGradeCode(0);
                    }
                        },
                        failure -> {
                            reviewContent.setMembershipGradeCode(0);
                            LOGGER.error("asyncGetMembershipGradeOfThisMember", failure.getStackTrace());
                        });

        ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<ReviewType>> reviewTypeByCategoryNo = boardApi.asyncGetReviewTypeByCategoryNo(categoryNo, setId);
        reviewTypeByCategoryNo.addCallback(success -> {
                    try {
                        reviewContent.setReviewType(success.getBody());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        reviewContent.setReviewType(null);
                    }
                },
                failure -> {
                    reviewContent.setReviewType(null);
                    LOGGER.error("asyncGetReviewTypeByCategoryNo", failure.getStackTrace());
                });

        reviewContent.setReviewCount((Integer) review.get().get("reviewCount"));
        reviewContent.setReviewAvgScore((Double) review.get().get("reviewAvgScore"));
        reviewContent.setContents((String) review.get().get("contents"));
        reviewContent.setCreateDt((String) review.get().get("createdDt"));
        reviewContent.setUpdateDt((String) review.get().get("updatedDt"));
        reviewContent.setMemberSrl(memberNo);
        reviewContent.setTitle((String) review.get().get("title"));
        reviewContent.setAccountSrl(Long.valueOf(review.get().get("accountNo").toString()));
        reviewContent.setMemberId((String) review.get().get("memberId"));
        reviewContent.setAccountSrl(Long.valueOf(review.get().get("accountNo").toString()));

        boolean isApiExecutionDone = false;
        while (!isApiExecutionDone) {
            if (gradeInfoOfThisMember.isDone() && optionInfo.isDone() && reviewTypeByCategoryNo.isDone()) {
                isApiExecutionDone = true;
            }
        }

        return reviewContent;
    }

    return new ReviewContent();
}
```

Comment: SO isn't for debugging your code for you. You don't even say what isn't working. Have you tried reducing your problem to a more simple test case? What have you tried, actually?

Comment: @FrankPavageau Sorry there's no test case. The problem is callback methods are not working. I made while statement in the end of method, because of waiting three AsyncRestTemplate results. dealApi.asyncGetDealOption, mktApi.asyncGetMembershipGradeOfThisMember(memberNo);
        gradeInfoOfThisMember, boardApi.asyncGetReviewTypeByCategoryNo

Comment: First of all, `ListenableFuture` as returned by `AsyncRestTemplate` is a Spring class, not the Guava one. Take your debugger, set breakpoints on the first async call and inside the various callbacks, and step into the method to find out on which thread or thread pool the task is submitted, look at the queue used, etc. Is the problem only with the callbacks, or are the `Future`s never completing either?

Comment: @FrankPavageau I debugged this already, but I can't resolve this. I think callback is working, but reviewContent is returned before callback methods work. When I debugged, If I stop at the point ".isDone" and wait few seconds, reviewContent is returned properly. I don't know what does this....thread is problem? or isDone is problem??

Comment: 'Not working properly' is not a problem description. Stupid title. Downvote.

Comment: @EJP I mean I can't get the value of optionaName, membershipGradeCode, reviewType these are result of AsyncRestTemplate.

Comment: @EJP and I edit my description. ^^

Comment: **This** last response to my comments should have been in your question from the start. If you withhold information about what's "not working properly", there's no way anyone can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is that the callbacks set properties on the object returned by your method. However, they are **also** executed asynchronously, and are not part of the `done` status of the `Future`: they are themselves executed once the `Future` is done, concurrently with the code in the `getRepresentativeReviewContent` method. Since the method returns as soon as all `Future`s are done, the properties aren't (all) set as they should.

Moreover, you didn't show the code for your `ReviewContent` object, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't declare the `optionType`, `membershipGradeCode` or `reviewType` fields as `volatile`. Since there are no barriers (such as `synchronized` blocks or `Lock`s) in the method, there's no guarantee in the Java Memory Model that the values set in the callbacks (i.e. in other threads) would be seen in the thread executing the `getRepresentativeReviewContent` method.

Callbacks should only be used for side-effects outside of your main execution path, since it's hard to coordinate with them: you would have to use things like a `CountDownLatch` to make sure they have all executed, that would make the code even more complex.

Just wait for the asynchronous results in a straight-forward way (the code is untested though):

```
try {
    // Not sure why you need to catch Exception here?
    // If it's for flow control (absent entry in a Map), it's a bad practice.
    // Just check it instead of catching NullPointerException.
    reviewContent.setOptionName((String) 
            ((Map<String, Object>) optionInfo.get().getBody().get("data"))
                    .get("dealTitle"));
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    LOGGER.error("asyncGetDealOption", e);
    reviewContent.setOptionName(null);
} catch (CancellationException | ExecutionException e) {
    LOGGER.error("asyncGetDealOption", e);
    reviewContent.setOptionName(null);
}
```

Another option is to compose the `Future`s, such as what can be done with Guava's [`Futures.transform`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#transform(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) to actually get the string you need out of the complete response, so you can just call `get()` on that composed `Future` to set your property. You'd still have to managed the errors, though.

Comment: Really helpful, Thx Frank! I will consider the side-effect out of the main path If I make callback method. Great!